# Adapting CppAD to Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am currently working on a project that requires the  [CppAD differentiation package](https://www.coin-or.org/CppAD/). The [repository](https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD) contains a cmake file, but I actually want to integrate the package into the default environment of Visual Studio 2017. I am currently stuck at the [configure.hpp](https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD/blob/master/cppad/configure.hpp.in), which includes defines such as

```
# define CPPAD_TAPE_ADDR_TYPE @cppad_tape_addr_type@
```

that generate unknown character errors.

Has anyone ever succesfully adapted the CppAD package to VS2017 or to any other version of VS?

Answer (score 1):

The file you mentioned is actually `configure.hpp.in` and it is used by CMake as a template to generate real `configure.hpp`. You may want to run CMake once to get the content of this file.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the purpose of this file, I will try it. Have you succesfully build CppAD with Visual studio , after an initial build with cmake?

Comment: No, I haven't switched for VS2017 from VS2015 yet and I've never seen this package before.